# Why are $C^0(\mathbb{R})$ and $C^{0,0} (\mathbb{R})$ the same spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, holder-spaces

$C^0(\mathbb{R})$ has the norm $\Vert f \Vert_{C^0(\mathbb{R})}$.

$C^{0,0} (\mathbb{R})$ has the norm $\Vert f \Vert_{C^0(\mathbb{R})} + \sup_{x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq y} |f(x) - f(y)|$.

I don't see how these are the same norms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
|f(x)-f(y) | \leq |f(x)| + |f(y)| \leq 2 \sup |f|.
$$
Therefore the norms are equivalent.

Comment: But then we have $C^{0,0} (\mathbb{R})$ has the norm $\Vert f \Vert_{C^0(\mathbb{R})} + 2\sup |f| = 3\sup|f| \neq \Vert f \Vert_{C^0(\mathbb{R})} = \sup|f|$ ?

Comment: The two norms are equivalent, and in particular they induce the same topology.

Comment: How does the inequality you've shown tell us they induce the same topology?

Comment: Equivalent norms induce the same topology...

Comment: Ok cool, I think I get it now. Just to check:
$$\Vert f \Vert_{C^{0,0}} = \Vert f \Vert_{C^{0}} + 2\sup|f| = 3\sup|f| = 3\Vert f \Vert_{C^{0}}.$$

Therefore we can say
$$\Vert f \Vert_{C^{0}} \le \Vert f \Vert_{C^{0,0}} \le 3\Vert f \Vert_{C^{0}}.$$

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.